# Usage of theme name in functions

Tags: functions, theme-development, localization

I've been studying some functions.php files to [get my head around theme development](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/162808/anxious-for-creating-own-independent-theme-especially-concerning-functions-ph), and I keep stumbling upon a reference to the theme name inside functions. Something like this:

```
<?php the_content( __( 'Continue reading <span class="meta-nav">&rarr;</span>', 'twentythirteen' ) ); ?>
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------^^
```

I find this odd, because [the codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_content) says the second variable of `the_content` should be a $stripteaser.

There are a lot of similar cases, for instance:

```
<?php edit_post_link( __( 'Edit', 'twentythirteen' ), '<span class="edit-link">', '</span>' ); ?>
-----------------------------------------^^
```

But also in `functions.php`

```
register_nav_menu( 'primary', __( 'Navigation Menu', 'twentythirteen' ) );
------------------------------------------------------------^^
```

Non of these seem to fulfil a variable position, so what do they do? What's the point of referring to the theme name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short: it's the so called »textdomain«.

The longer explanation: 
If you look accurate on your first example, you'll see, that this parameter is not the second parameter for `the_content` but for the Funktion `__()`:

```
<?php 
the_content( 
    __( 
        'Continue reading <span class="meta-nav">&rarr;</span>', 
        'twentythirteen' 
    ) 
); 
?>
```

This function is part of the internationalisation (»I18n«) functions to make text translatable.

The textdomain acts as an identifier for translation files, which are typically stored in `wp-content/languages` for themes. So if you want to use this theme in German language for example, the language files would be named like `twentythirteen-de_DE.mo` and `twentythirteen-de_DE.po`.

`de_DE` is the so called »locale«, <del>which is typically defined in the constant `WPLANG`</del> which is (since WordPress version 4.0) stored in the option `WPLANG`.

`.mo` files are binary files, used by WordPress for the translation and `.po` files are editable (text) files to define translation for each string used in the source.

Some useful sources on internationalisation is the official documentation: 
http://codex.wordpress.org/I18n_for_WordPress_Developers